# How can I get the two highest numbers in an unlimited *args list?

Tags: python-3.x

Ok so first off I know how to do this if it were not in an *args list, but long story short it has to be in a function that creates uses an *args list.

I am trying to print the two largest numbers in the list.

```
def findTwoLargest(*args):
    max1 = 0
    max1 = max(args)
    args.sort()
    max2 = 0
    max2 = args[-2]
    return max1, max2
    
m1, m2 = findTwoLargest(-2, 30, -4, 9, 1, 6)
print(m1, m2)
```

Answer (score 1):

`args` is a `tuple`, so you cannot use `sort` method on it. You can use `sorted` function instead:

```
def findTwoLargest(*args):
    max1 = 0
    max1 = max(args)
    max2 = 0
    max2 = sorted(args)[-2]
    return max1, max2
    
m1, m2 = findTwoLargest(-2, 30, -4, 9, 1, 6)
print(m1, m2)
```

A short version:

```
def findTwoLargest(*args):
    max2, max1 = sorted(args)[-2:]
    return max1, max2
```